# Unable to remove public folders in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, public-folders, mailbox

I am trying to remove a public folder database on an Exchange 2007 SP2 mailbox server so the role can be removed. I used the PowerShell script that comes with Exchange (MoveAllReplicas.ps1) to migrate the replicas to another server. I verified that they are there and removed the replicas on this server. However there are five, all seem to be related to Outlook 2003  that give me this error whenever I try and remove them:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft Exchange Error
--------------------------------------------------------
Action 'Remove' could not be performed on object 'SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY'.

SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY
Failed
Error:
The folder '\NON_IPM_SUBTREE\SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY' or some of its subfolder(s) encountered errors and could not be deleted.

MapiExceptionPartialCompletion: Unable to delete folder. (hr=0x40680, ec=0)
Diagnostic context:
    Lid: 18969   EcDoRpcExt2 called [length=54]
    Lid: 27161   EcDoRpcExt2 returned [ec=0x0][length=85][latency=0]
    Lid: 23226   --- ROP Parse Start ---
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropDeleteFolder [29]
    Lid: 17082   ROP Error: 0x80070005
    Lid: 19297  
    Lid: 21921   StoreEc: 0x80070005
    Lid: 27962   ROP: ropNone [0]
    Lid: 26881  
    Lid: 21817   ROP Failure: 0x80070005
    Lid: 24721  
    Lid: 20625   StoreEc: 0x80070005
```

I am under a time constraint so I'm hoping someone out there will be able to help me.

Comment: Do you have Outlook 2003 or older clients?

Comment: Do you have any pre Exchange 2007 servers in your organization?

Comment: Yes, so this ended up biting me hard. I assumed that deleting was deleting the replica on the server. Turns out thats wrong and I ended up deleting all the public folders in our Organization... Restoring from backup now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a posting from technet detailing this exact issue
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/46124982-7161-4241-b6e0-093cedeeda76

Looks like using ADSI Edit to delete out the public folders was the final step needed

Comment: This solution does look exactly like what I needed, unfortunately I was trying to do something I shouldn't. So anyone that comes across this problem be wary. And this looks like it will solve it.